# Change big collection into unique List of collections

Tags: c#

I have a big list of objects and in this object there is a category ID something like:

```
    var list = new List<Example>
    {
        new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }},
        new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }},
        new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }},
        new Example {CatId = 2, Value = new { }},
        new Example {CatId = 2, Value = new { }},
        new Example {CatId = 3, Value = new { }}

        // and so on
    };
```

So I am looking for making this complicated list more organized like list of lists of unique elements

something like:

```
    var result = new List<List<Example>>
    {
        new List<Example>
        {
            new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }},
            new Example {CatId = 2, Value = new { }},
            new Example {CatId = 3, Value = new { }}
        },
        new List<Example>
        {
            new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }},
            new Example {CatId = 2, Value = new { }}
        },
        new List<Example>
        {
            new Example {CatId = 1, Value = new { }}
        }
    }
```

Problem is I do not what to use, group by will not fix my case, so how to do this in most efficient way.

Comment: What you posted aren't collections or even C# code. It's unclear how you want to group the objects too. Why does `{cid:1, val}` appear in 3 different places? If you have any collection that implemenst `IEnumerable<T>` you can use LINQ to batch and group objects

Comment: I think this question would be clearer if you gave an example of the class you are using, and what kind of queries you are using.

Comment: Whatever the logic is, there's probably a LINQ operator that can implement it. The logic is unclear though. Are you grouping by some property? Or by sequence values?

Comment: There change pseudo code to c#

Comment: are you trying to partition this into multiple lists, such that category id is unique in each list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is about partitioning, it's the sort of thing that is easy to do in a database query, but in c# you need to create some key with a partition number that you can then use to `.GroupBy`.

The partitioning itself is a grouping

```
var projected = list.GroupBy(x => x.CatId)
        .SelectMany( g => g.Select( ( x, i ) => new { Item = x, rn = i + 1 } ) );
```

This gives you records that look like:

```
{"Item":{"CatId":1,"Value":{}},"rn":1}
{"Item":{"CatId":1,"Value":{}},"rn":2}
{"Item":{"CatId":1,"Value":{}},"rn":3}
{"Item":{"CatId":2,"Value":{}},"rn":1}
{"Item":{"CatId":2,"Value":{}},"rn":2}
{"Item":{"CatId":3,"Value":{}},"rn":1}
```

As you can see that `rn` ("row number") value can be used to group by:

```
var result = projected.GroupBy(x => x.rn, x => x.Item);
```

This gives us:

```
[{"CatId":1,"Value":{}},{"CatId":2,"Value":{}},{"CatId":3,"Value":{}}]
[{"CatId":1,"Value":{}},{"CatId":2,"Value":{}}]
[{"CatId":1,"Value":{}}]
```

So, all in 1 go:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.CatId)
        .SelectMany( g => g.Select( ( x, i ) => new { Item = x, rn = i + 1 } ) )
        .GroupBy(x => x.rn, x => x.Item);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AlTfk8

Comment: Why the `+ 1` in `rn = i + 1`?

Comment: @RandRandom no reason really. Just makes it 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2